# Leer URL cada 60 segundos en Python

Tags: python, url, data

Quiero est URL cada 60 segundos, tengo este código. La dirección URL me trae datos de acciones

```
import requests
url="https:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
r = requests.get(url)
text = r.text 
print (text)
```

¿cómo puedo hacer una funcion para que me la lea cada 60 segundos?

Comment: No uses mayúsculas, equivale a gritar

Comment: ¿Bloqueante o no bloqueante? Es decir, ¿entre lectura y lectura pretendes que el proceso siga haciendo algo o no?. La opción directa es usar `time.sleep(60)`, pero ten en cuenta que es bloqueante y durante esos 60 segundos no puedes hacer nada más a no ser que uses concurrencia. Sería bueno que añadieras algunos detalles sobre el uso real que le vas a dar.

Comment: Como seria no bloqueante?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa time. Espero que te sirva

```
import requests,time
while True:
    url="https:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    r = requests.get(url)
    text = r.text 
    print (text)
    time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: si desearia que se pare a las 8 hora de lectura?

Comment: @NapoleonRicaurte Puesto que en 8 horas hay 480 minutos, puedes hacer que el bucle se repita 480 veces, en lugar de infinitas veces.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias esto me ayudo bastante!